# Regex validation with multiple subpatterns

Tags: javascript, c#, regex

In this post. [Parsing all possible types of varying architectural dimension input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22794466/parsing-all-possible-types-of-varying-architectural-dimension-input/32576929#32576929)
Can someone explain why the accepted answer fails regex validation when I try to test it on this site. https://regex101.com/ It is saying that the subpattern feet and inches are defined multiple times. which they are.

Is this just a difference between C# and JavaScript?

Here is the regex I was trying in regex101. After I removed the double back slashes.

```
^\s*(?<minus>-)?\s*(((?<feet>\d+)(?<inch>\d{2})(?<sixt>\d{2}))|((?<feet>[\d.]+)')?[\s-]*((?<inch>\d+)?[\s-]*((?<numer>\d+)/(?<denom>\d+))?\")?)\s*$
```

Comment: post the regex101 link you have been tested. And note that you should replace double backslashes with single backslash in regex101.

Comment: If you mean `((?<feet>\\d+)(?<inch>\\d{2})(?<sixt>\\d{2}))|((?<feet>[\\d.]+)')?[\\s-]*((?<inch>\\d+)?[\\s-]*((?<numer>\\d+)/(?<denom>\\d+))?\")?`, it contains named captures that are not supported by the JS regex engine.

Comment: I guess this is a case for [Learning Regular Expressions](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2759417/3832970).